# Live content edit on screen chrome dev tool

Tags: google-chrome, console

I had read a blog around 4 or 5 months ago about tips and tricks of chrome dev tool. I am not sure what exact keyword I used but I land to a blog and it was awesome.

In that blog there were some tips of chrome dev tools. One of the most liked feature was live content edit on screen directly without editing content on Element tab of chrome.

According to that blog we first need to activate that feature via typing some `keyword.mode = on' and it activates it.

Can anyone share that what is the exact `keyword` to activate the live content edit on screen directly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From dev tools, simply open up the console and run `document.body.contentEditable = true`